# What is the hexadecimal representation?

Tags: number-systems

A signed number in $2's$ compliment notation with $16-$bit register $P=DFA0$

What is the value of  $P*4$?

I  have tried $P*4=0111111010000000$ but sign bit changed from $1$ to $0$.
What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: The shifted value `11 0111 1110 1000 0000` does not fit into a 16-bit register, i.e. the multiplication overflows. If you ignore overflow your value is correct.

Comment: $DFA0$ in twos complement represents $-8288$ in decimal. $4 \times -8288 = -32384 < -2^{15}$ so you have an overflow condition.

Answer (score 0):

The value overflowed the range of the register.  A $16$ bit twos complement register can represent $-2^{15}$ to $2^{15}-1$ or $-32768$ to $32767$.  $DFA0$ is a little more negative than $-5\cdot 2^{12}$, so when you multiply it by $4$ you get something like $-20\cdot 2^{12}=-81920$, which is out of range.  I ignored the lower order bits because they do not impact the problem.

Comment: @Arthur:  yes.  Thanks